# How to make predictions from a GLMM model where the prediction space has fewer independent variables than were used to generate the model?

Tags: mixed-model, predictive-models, biostatistics, glmm, predictor

**THE PROBLEM**

I have a Generalized Linear Mixed Effects (GLMM) model that is relating counts of an organism to relevant environmental covariates. Once this model is generated, I intend to apply it to areas where observations have not yet occurred by making predictions about what counts we'd expect given the environmental covariates. The observations used to build the model and the area where the model (what I call 'prediction space') will be applied have identical environmental covariate information (e.g., V1 = distance to important feature 1, V2 = distance to important feature 2, etc.)

However, additional covariates have been included in the GLMM in addition to these environmental covariates that I don't think can be similarly represented in the prediction space. For example, the counts used for the model may have been made from surveys conducted by different methods (e.g., boat versus airplane) so the vessel type has been included as a fixed effect to control for  and understand potential variability in counts related to survey method. Also, the surveys have occurred over the last 40 years, so Year is included as a random effect to control for variability in counts as a function of Year. Obviously, when predicting about what might be observed in a space that has yet to be sampled, there is no way to assign vessel type or year.

**THE QUESTIONS**

I have the following questions for which I have been unable to come across a clearly articulated answer:

1. For making predictions from a GLMM, how does one handle instances where a fixed effect can only be represented in the model but not the prediction space?
2. For making predictions from a GLMM, how does one handle instances where a random effect can only be represented in the model but not the prediction space?
3. If neither #1 or #2 are possible, or statistically justifiable, what additional options exist for handling situations such as those outlined here?

**Thanks in advance for your assistance!**

Comment: Assuming there is no trend over years, the year random effect will be part of your error variance when predicting

Answer (score 0):

For your boat/airplane problem, the simplest solution is to provide estimates for both types of observation. If you are going to test your model with one specific mode of observation, then make predictions for that mode.

For the random effect, the comment from @kjetil b halvorsen is correct. If there is no trend over years, then the variance of the random effect will just add to the variance of your estimates. Make sure that you have ruled out trends over years, however. Assuming a lack of trend for data collected over a course of 4 decades can be dangerous.